# How $\log p$ distributed?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, probability-distributions, prime-numbers

From literature we know: If a number $n \le x$ is chosen at random, and choose $\lambda \ge 0$ and $j$ not too large (say $\lambda ,j \le 20$) then the number of primes in $[ n , n + \log(n) ]$ is approximately Poisson-distributed (ref [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Poisson_distribution_and_prime_numbers)).

***Question:*** *what is then (approx.) the distibution of $\log p$ of a type?*

$p$ denotes a prime.

Comment: What is $p$, you didn't define it. Are you asking what is the distribution for log of a Poisson random variable?

Comment: $p$ is prime. To your question, yes, can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $\mathcal{P}$ to denote the Poisson distribution and $\mathbb{P}[A]$ to denote the probability of some event $A$.

Let $X \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ with cdf $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x]$ and let $L = \ln(X)$. Then,
$$
F_L(x) = \mathbb{P}[L \leq x] = \mathbb{P}[\ln(X) \leq x] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq e^x] = F_X(e^x).
$$

Since we know $X \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$, we can plug in:
$$
F_L(x) = F_X(e^x) = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor e^x \rfloor} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!},
$$
which is enough to completely determine the distribution.

Comment: thanks. To avoid any doubts, would you define what are $\mathcal{P}$ and $\Bbb P$?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi added first sentence notation clarification.